# Contar registros do mysql no formato X de Y para exibir em formulário estilo wizard

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou com um problema para contar os registros de uma tabela no banco de dados e mostrar ela como nesse exemplo: 1(X) de 10(Y) quando clicar em "next" do formulário seria 2(X) de 10(Y) e assim por diante, conforme vai avançando o formulário vai aumentando +1 no valor de X.

Para listar todas as perguntas cadastradas no banco de dados uso o seguinte código:

```
<?php
        include_once "../../conexao.php";
        $sql_questionario = "SELECT * FROM `questionario_perguntas` ORDER BY RAND()";
        $query_questionario = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_questionario);

        while ($dados_questionario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_questionario)) {
            ?>
                <fieldset>

                    <div class="divider-text gap-top-20 gap-bottom-45">
                        <span>Questão X de Y</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- start way to communicate -->
                    <div class="unit check" id="">
                        <div class="group">
                            <h2><?php echo "$dados_questionario[pergunta]";?></h2>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                </fieldset>
```

Alguém para me ajudar? 
Abraço.

Comment: Seu caso é o mesmo que uma paginação, com a peculiaridade de ser 1 item por página.

Comment: Coloque o link aqui por favor da resposta que serve para meu caso. Poi ficou muito vaga essa justificativa. Obrigado

Comment: O link está no quadro amarelo em cima da pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
...
$query_questionario = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_questionario);
$total = $query_questionario->num_rows;
$question = 0;

        while ($dados_questionario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_questionario)) {
            ?>
                <fieldset>

                    <div class="divider-text gap-top-20 gap-bottom-45">
                        <span>Questão <?= ++question ?> de <?= $total ?></span>
...
```

Você pode usar a função `mysqli_num_rows` para obter a quantidade de resultados obtidos e salvar em uma variável para ficar exibindo. Você pode ver mais sobre essa função na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

E utiliza outra variável como contador para exibir o número da questão atual dentro do loop.

Comment: Apesar do tópico ter sido fechado, informando que o problema era o mesmo que o do link. Deixo claro aqui que essa solução informada pelo @thiago-magalães foi exatamente o que eu precisava. Pois meu formulário não precisa de paginação por se tratar de STEP ele só avança após clicar em AVANÇAR e com isso ele mesmo cria sua paginação. Agradeço ao amigo Thiago pela resposta eficiente, e para quem busca o mesmo problema que eu não vai precisar decifrar o código de outra pessoa com problema que não é o mesmo para conseguir resolver. Muito obrigado Thiago, que Deus abençoe você; Grande abraço